# CORTEX lpc1768 tutorial

Tags: arm, cortex-m

I need some tutorial for working with cortex lpc1768.i think it doesn't have good document on it. please give me some information and tutorials for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LPC generally does a good job with their docs.

Anything with an ARM in it though you also need the TRM (technical reference manual) for that core and the ARM ARM (ARM Architectural Reference Manual).  Instead of one unified ARM ARM they have split it into families (thankfully, it was becoming unusable) being a cortex m you want the ARMv7 TRM and/or ARM ARM.

Here are some sample programs.

https://github.com/dwelch67/mbed_samples

Comment: i want sample code just for lpc1768, this site is not what i want.

Comment: you need to clarify what you are looking for.  the mbed_samples are lpc1768 example programs, very simple ones in fact.  If you are not looking for lpc1768 examples then what is it that you want?  The lpc and arm docs are very good, do you have those documents?  the readme on the mbed_samples will help you to find those documents.

Comment: @dwelch: `LPC generally does a good job with their docs`  I think you mean NXP.

Comment: right Philips, NXP, or whatever their name happens to be this week, sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 4):

NXP has a big driver library with loads of example code, but it is somewhat hard to find: 
[CMSIS driver lib](http://ics.nxp.com/support/documents/microcontrollers/zip/lpc17xx.cmsis.driver.library.zip) - somehow the link is missing on the nxp.com web pages. I got it from the [code_red](http://support.code-red-tech.com/CodeRedWiki/NXPDriverLibraries) pages.

This driver library has code samples for almost all peripherials included in this microcontroller.